# How does the DocuSign API work?

Tags: docusignapi, vtiger

I am very confused as to how the API of DocuSign works, I tried looking it up here:
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm

But that didn't help me much, especially not because I need to implement DocuSign into the open source version of Vtiger.

Does anybody here know a site where I can learn more about DocuSign and how I can combine it with Vtiger open source?

As for what I already tried that is nothing, I first need to make a functional design which is kind of hard to do when you don't even understand the basic API.

I would really appreciate it.

I have never worked with an API before, so this is all new for me.

Comment: Have you tried to use the DocuSign web application (https://demo.docusign.net) to upload documents, add recipients, add signatures tabs, send, and sign? I would recommend becoming familiar with the web application first so you have an idea about feature/function, and that will help point you in the right direction for API calls needed to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the API overview instead of the reference guide?   Check this out:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview

You can also look at the API Recipes to see some starting examples of what you can do in any language.  I believe VTiger is written in PHP so you can find the PHP code to copy and paste to get you started.

Comment: That is the API I also linked in the question and that one doesn't help me due to me finding it confusing.